# Error in installing packages 'RGtk2' and 'rattle' in R

Tags: r, rattle

I tried to install R packages 'rattle' but when I typed

```
install.packages('rattle')
```

it returns

```
Warning in install.packages :
dependency ‘RGtk2’ is not available
```

So I tried install 'RGtk2',

```
install.packages('RGtk2')
```

it returns

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘RGtk2’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

My computer is windows 8.1, R version 3.2.3 and I'm working on the R studio.

Comment: One option is to install `install.packages('versions')` if not available, then get the tar.gz (on linux) or binary zip on windows. install it, and then you can install a suitable version `install.versions(rattle, <v.number>)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for comment. I guess this is not a problem of R version. It seems that this kind of problem occurs in other versions of R.

Comment: It is a version issue. RGtk2 requires an R version >=3.4. You need ti find an earlier version of RGtk2 that allows R 3.2.3

Comment: @Dason Yes. Thanks! I updated R and made it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible solution as mentioned is to install an older version of RGtk2. For Windows this might be:

> install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/RGtk2_2.20.31.zip", 
>       repos=NULL)

Further suggestions can be found at https://rattle.togaware.com/rattle-install-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 3):

For linux users, this worked for me :

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RGtk2/RGtk2_2.20.30.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

RGtk2 installed, you can run `install.packages("rattle")`

You may also need to install `libgtk2.0-dev` and `libxml2-dev` before installing RGtk2 !

Conf : Ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety) and R version 3.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Listed below are the known compatible versions which will definitely work:

1. Try to downgrade your R version to 3.3.2.
2. Download RGtk2 version with 2.20.33 and manually install it.
3. Install rattle version as 4.1

Answer (score 1):

I use macOS and used the following instructions to sought this out.

Step 1:

```
brew install gtk+
brew install --with-x11 cairo
```

Step 2:

```
install.packages("rattle")
```

There would be loads of red lines on the console, while you're installing rattle, but it's OK. It will work out.